# Clojure - Evaluating returned function from higher order function

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

If I run a higher order function in the repl, or something that returns a function, like below, is there any way to later retrieve the returned function (the value that is returned by the repl) and evaluate it?

```
user> #(% 5 5)
#function[user/eval13160/fn--13161]
```

To explain the reason for the question, I'm playing around with [http-kit](http://www.http-kit.org/), and ran the function `run-server`. It was only after execution that I realized that the function returns a function that is required to stop the server, and so I've been trying to figure how to use the function that was returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, you can access previous REPL values with `*1`:

```
user=> #(% 5 5)
#object[user$eval3$fn__4 0x487db668 "user$eval3$fn__4@487db668"]
user=> (*1 +)
10
```

There's also `*2` and `*3` for trailing values from previous evaluations, and `*e` for prior exceptions.

You could also `def` the result:

```
(def my-fn #(% 5 5))
(def my-fn *1) ;; or do it later
```